# Why aren't my ArrayList items removing themselves when they disapear?

Tags: java

I am trying to get my Asteroids game in Java to have the ArrayList container be removed once it's off screen. I figured out how to stop having it print when off screen, but can see in my console the array continues to grow. Not sure where to go from here.

I think the way I can get them to be removed when off screen is by either using the remove or set feature with arrayLists. Visually everything is disappearing right, but in the console my ArrayList is still growing. I thought about setting a limit of how long it can be, but not sure if there is a better way than that.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class AsteroidGame extends Frame {

    private int FrameWidth = 500;
    private int FrameHeight = 400;

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        AsteroidGame world = new AsteroidGame();
        world.show();
        world.run();
    }

    public AsteroidGame() {
        setTitle("Asteroid Game0");
        setSize(FrameWidth, FrameHeight);
        addKeyListener(new keyDown());
        addWindowListener(new CloseQuit());
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            movePieces();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList asteroids = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList rockets = new ArrayList();
    private Station station = new Station(FrameWidth / 2, FrameHeight - 20);

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        station.paint(g);
        Iterator astIt = asteroids.iterator();
        while (astIt.hasNext()) {
            Asteroid rock = (Asteroid) astIt.next();
            if (rock.y >= 400 || rock.x >= 500){
                rock = null;
            } else {
                rock.paint(g);
            }

        }
        Iterator rocIt = rockets.iterator();
        while (rocIt.hasNext()) {
            Rocket rock = (Rocket) rocIt.next();
            if (rock.y >= 400 || rock.x >= 500) {
                rock = null;
            } else {
                rock.paint(g);
            }
        }

    }

    public void movePieces() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
            Asteroid newRock = new Asteroid(FrameWidth * Math.random(), 20, 10 * Math.random() - 5, 3 + 3 * Math.random());
            if (newRock.y >= 500 || newRock.x >= 500){

                asteroids.remove(0);

            } else{
                asteroids.add(newRock);
            }
            System.out.println(asteroids.size());

        }

        Iterator astIt = asteroids.iterator();
        while (astIt.hasNext()) {
            Asteroid rock = (Asteroid) astIt.next();
            if (rock.y >= 400 || rock.x >= 500) {
                rock = null;
            } else {
                rock.move();
                station.checkHit(rock);
            }


        }
        Iterator rocIt = rockets.iterator();
        while (rocIt.hasNext()) {
            Rocket rock = (Rocket) rocIt.next();
            if (rock.y >= 400 || rock.x >= 500) {
                rock = null;
            } else {
                rock.move(asteroids);
            }

        }

    }

    private class gameMover extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                movePieces();
                repaint();
                try {
                    sleep(100);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When do you need to remove the asteroids? I see in the code you set each asteroid that goes over 400 (y or x) to null, but you never remove them from the array that way. You could add `asteroids.remove(rock)` or `astIt.remove()` and theoretically you wouldn't even need to set it to null that way as the garbage collector will take care of it for you.

Comment: Also, why do you remove the first asteroid in the array if the new asteroid gets spawned over 500 (y or x)?

Comment: I need to have them removed at anything beyond x 500 and y 400. Is null not what I needed but instead removing the rock itself?

I removed the first asteroid because I thought by the time it was off screen moving it over with a new asteroid would have fixed it? Been on this for days with little help so sorry if the logic doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
rock = null;
```

to:

```
astIt.remove();
```

Assigning `null` to the variable that has been assigned the value of an element of a List does absolutely nothing to either the List or the element in it; it only affects the value that the variable *holds*.

---

As an aside, nice variable name choice of `rock` - it is appropraite for both types of object - either an abbreviation of "rocket" or a reasonable synonym for an astroid.

Comment: Thank you a ton for the help... I feel really stupid right now. I've been on this one thing for days unsure of what was going wrong.

Comment: Happy to help. This is what this site is all about - helping people and hopefully changing them from sad to happy!

Comment: Wish school professors were more like this. Have been thrown pretty far into the deep end before.

Comment: You know what they say... *If you can't do it, teach it*. As an aside, when assigning a task I always (try to!) ask myself "have I set the person up for success".

Answer (score 0):

Change `rock = null;` to `asteroids.remove(rock);` or `astIt.remove();`
and it should be fine, also no need to set the variable to null as the garbage collector will take care of it for you.
**EDIT**
Actually `asteroids.remove(rock);` will throw an exception as said in the comments of this answer, so nevermind it and use the other.

Also I think when in `movePieces()` you create a new rock and you check if this new rock is outside the screen, I don't think removing the first asteroid in the ArrayList is correct as you will not add the new rock (which may be right if the rock can actually randomly spawn outside the screen) but you will also remove a maybe fine working asteroid from the ArrayList (and thus from the game and the screen).

So, personally I would change that part of code to:

```
if (Math.random() < 0.3) {
        Asteroid newRock = new Asteroid(FrameWidth * Math.random(), 20, 10 * Math.random() - 5, 3 + 3 * Math.random());
        if (!(newRock.y >= 500 || newRock.x >= 500)){

            asteroids.add(newRock);
        }
        System.out.println(asteroids.size());

    }
```

But tell me if this works for you.

Comment: 1) `asteroids.remove(rock)` with throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` and 2) the rest of your answer is a copy of mine - ie plagiarism, which is frowned upon. Please don't do this again.

Comment: @Bohemian For point one I forgot, even tho I've encountered that problem myself yesterday ahah. For point two, I'm sorry you think I copied you, but I did not, I didn't even see your answer till I got the inbox of your comment.